WOWLAN with OpenVPN stops working after a few minutes
Simple, I want to WOWLAN. I already have WOL working with the app/software WOLOW companion.
I setup OPENVPN on my router and got it connected to my phone, so when I connect to the VPN my public IP is the same as my home-network. However WOWLAN stops working after roughly 5 min when my computer has been turned off whilst WOLAN works every time no matter how long the computer has been turned off for.
Additionally WOLAN works through the broadcast address sent from my computers network card whilst WOWLAN only works when sent directly to the network card.
So really the main problem is why WOWLAN stops working after a few minutes

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The two biggest causes of this is either the sleeping STA (wireless client) failing to maintain its 802.11 association to the AP (wireless router), or the router losing its ARP table entry for the client in question, and the client failing to respond to ARP requests.
Can you get your router to show you a list of connected wireless devices? If so, can you see if the target machine is dropping off the Wi-Fi network after about 5 minutes? Separately, do you have a way to see the router's ARP table? Can you see if the router's ARP entry for that host disappears after 5 minutes?

Hi, sorry for the delay. Yes I was able to see the a list of attached devices and my computer was eventually removed from the list when turned off, however I was able to turn the computer on for short while even when it was shown to have been abandoned by my router. I don’t know how to add my device into a static ARP table. I have a netgear orbi rbk750
